# Serverless framework, subscribe multiple topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am having difficulties on subscribing all my topics to a function handler.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
functions:
xxxxx:
handler:xxxx
events:
- sns: arn:aws:sns:xxxx:xxxxx:*
```

When I try to add all topics that I have without a wildcard, I am facing this error:

> An error occurred bla bla bla - The final policy size (20526) is bigger than the limit (20480)

How can I subscribe all my topics to a function handler while avoiding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't subscribe to multiple topics using wildcards like you're doing (as far as I know). You have to list each topic out like so:

```
functions:
  xxxxx:
    handler:xxxx
    events:
      - sns: arn:aws:sns:xxxx:xxxxx:a
      - sns: arn:aws:sns:xxxx:xxxxx:b
      - sns: arn:aws:sns:xxxx:xxxxx:c
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although thats exactly my problem, when i try to subscribe alot of them i get this error :
```The final policy size (20526) is bigger than the limit (20480)```

thats why i started a journey of finding an alternative way of declaring them all in a wildcard or something.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you hit a hard limit here.
As a workaround, you could try to split those subscriptions in 2 lambdas with the same handler:

```
functions:
  myLambda_A_1:
    handler:myHandler1
    events:
      - sns: arn:aws:sns:xxxx:xxxxx:a
      - sns: arn:aws:sns:xxxx:xxxxx:b
      - sns: arn:aws:sns:xxxx:xxxxx:c
      - ...
  myLambda_A_2:
    handler:myHandler1  // <= same handler as the previous lambda
    events:
      - ...
      - sns: arn:aws:sns:xxxx:xxxxx:x
      - sns: arn:aws:sns:xxxx:xxxxx:y
      - sns: arn:aws:sns:xxxx:xxxxx:z
```